# Avoid repeating lots of queries every time

Tags: django, performance, django-views, django-queryset

I'm done building a website, there's a lots of views that contains many queries
**My question is How can I avoid repeating some queries from views that will be visited by users many time?**.

Here is an example of views.py

```
@access_to(['is_admin','is_job_seeker'])
def negotiationView(request,slug,id,code):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Group,slug=slug) 
    nego = get_object_or_404(Negotiation,id=id,code=code)

    related_negos = Negotiation.objects.filter(tag=nego.tag)
    # New tag can be created every 2 months or more
    all_jobs = obj.job_offers.filter(published=True) # new job can be added every week
```

As you can, each time I visit that page, the same query will repeat..

Any hint will be helpful, Thank you in advance!

Comment: You typically can not, since typically a webserver is considered - except for the database - to be stateless. You can do some caching, with for example [`django-cachalot`](http://django-cachalot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @WillemVanOnsem, with `Django-cachalot` is there a way to tell it after how many days or months to reload real contents instead of cache. doesn't django provide one, rather than any third-party packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a caching layer to your application. One of the technologies that can be used with Django is [Memcached](https://memcached.org/).

Here's info in Django docs about setting up caching with Memcached: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/cache/#memcached

Also same page has info about using caching in Django in general, including [per-view cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/cache/#the-per-view-cache)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you edit your answer with an example of how to use it in a view?

Comment: Awesome. Found it in the documentation.in the meanwhile, waiting for other answers that might be better. thank you very much

Comment: The second link I posted, `per-view cache` specifies a decorator you can add to a view or in urlconf if you are using class-based views.